# What is a good pratice to store row counts in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I’m designing a huge database, which in a few months will have a huge amount of data. The database will be projected in **MySQL** and all tables will use **InnoDB engine**. So, since now, I’ve been trying to develop the best model possible. So, let’s begin!

A simplified schema of tables can be seen below:

```
(table)
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| users                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| PK user_id        int        unsigned        auto_increment  |
| (all other columns with user data)                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

(table)
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| products                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| PK product_id     int        unsigned        auto_increment  |
| (all other columns with product data)                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

(table) user’s favorite products
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| user_favproducts                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| PK FK user        int        unsigned (on delete cascade) |
| PK FK product     int        unsigned (on delete cascade) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

**The user can only favorite a product once, and that’s why user and product are primary keys in user_favproducts. If user deletes account, all their favorite products will be also deleted; and if a product was deleted, all their favorites will be deleted.**

Let’s suppose a scenario where *user_favproducts* has millions of rows with many users and many products. So, I’ve tried thinking about the best solution to get optimal performance: Imagine that every time a user opens a profile, the user will be shown a count of favorite products to the respective profile.

### Alternative A

Simple: Get the count using SQL, as below:

```
SELECT count(product) WHERE user = 1;
```

For InnoDB engine, I’m not sure how it will work when a table has millions of rows or more.

Every time a profile is shown, the count of favorite products will also be shown. This means I would have to execute the SQL above every time. Thinking about performance, I don’t know if is the better way.

### Alternative B

Store the count of favorite products in a metadata table, as below:

```
(table)
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| user_metadata                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| PK FK user        int        unsigned                    |
| favproducts       int        unsigned                    |
| last_update       timestamp  on update current_timestamp |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

To maintain this table updated, I considered three alternatives:

#### Alternative B.1

Schedule a cron job task that will run a script at periodic time. Then this script will update the count, as below:

```
* Get count
result = SELECT count(product) WHERE user = 1;
* Update count
UPDATE user_metadata SET favproducts = result WHERE user = 1;
```

#### Alternative B.2

Make a trigger where always, when a new insertion happens in user_favproducts, will update user_metadata by using an SQL, as below:

```
UPDATE user_metadata SET favproducts = favproducts + 1 WHERE user = 1;
```

#### Alternative B.3

Instead of using a trigger, use the same sql above, but this time it will be executed by a script, the same script that do a insertion.

## Main question

My question is: Which approach from above will perform the best in counting how many user favorited products exist?

Comment: A bit of advice: premature optimization is evil.

Comment: Another bit of advice: if you already know you are going to use a huge amount of data why not choosing a DB that was designed to handle huge amounts of data like cassandra for example?

Comment: @STTLCU yes, I know about it. But when you do a data model without think, at least, about the next six months... you probably will have an headache and more work in the future. My objective is just to couple the best performance as possible. If the best solution even with less data, for exemple, is alternative B, then I already can make that table in my scheme.

Comment: @CaiqueMonteiroAraujo and that's exactly why you should make sure that your data layer is well encapsulate so as soon as you have to make any change to it (potentially even changing database) your application won't explode (or requires months of refactoring).

Comment: @Marco well... the system is more complex than I shown, I need to have a support for complex/flexible queries. If I use Cassandra I will have to do a lot of things to my needs work well. MySQL is a free solution that has all support I need for now. Maybe in the future I can transfer some data for Cassandra database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is a rather subjective matter.

Firstly, "huge" numbers for humans are not necessarily "huge" numbers for relational databases. Millions of rows are not a problem, as long as you can use indexes for searching. So, your simplified example `SELECT count(product) WHERE user = 1;` will almost certainly return in milliseconds as long as there is an index on the user column.

The alternative you're considering - adding the number of favourite products to the users table - is generally known as denormalization. There are many problems with denormalization - once you have two sources of truth for a fact, you have to make sure you keep them in sync, or you end up with hilarious bugs. Cron jobs mean that there will be time when the two sources of truth disagree; triggers are hard to maintain, and often introduce their own performance problems.

My general approach is a bit of effort, but if performance is you concern, it's the only way to stay sane...

Firstly, work out what your data size is going to be, create a test environment, create the most normalized schema on that environment, and populate it with test data (there are tools like DbMonster that help with this).

Once you have a test environment, figure out the queries your application will need to run, what the response time target is, and test the queries. You might use a unit testing framework for this.

Optimize those queries. Put LOTS of energy into that - it's the best time you can spend.

If you really cannot get your queries to fit in the target response times, see if you can fix the problem with hardware. Memory, RAM and SSDs are much cheaper than developer time.

If that doesn't work, consider denormalization. If you do this, write unit tests to protect yourself against bugs, or unexpected side-effects. For instance, your simplified trigger would slow down inserts into the `user_favproducts`  table if accessing the user is slow.

Whatever you do, do not optimize for performance until you know, and can measure, that you have a problem. The maintainability impact can be severe, and it's much easier to make a slow, correct application faster than make a fast, incorrect application work properly.

Comment: I like your answer because it talk about one of my big preoccupation using that denormalization: two sources of truth for a fact. As you said, maybe the better way is do multiple tests, see what works better and what can I improve. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative A will be the slowest. This might not be significant with just a few records, but it will for sure take a while when counting millions of records.

Alternatives B.2 und B.3 are almost the same. But using B.2 will save you one roundtrip to the database. Using a cron job (like in B.1) is not an option. Users want to see the results of their actions immediately.

So from a performance perspekcive, triggers for the insert and delete operations of table “user favorites products” should be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that if it is an optimization approach but definitely it is an improvement by changing logic.
As discussed, your both option have some pros and cons.

every time counting from db is not good, it will overload that table.

Putting metadata in a separate table and updating it always is not good until more than one application utilizing same thing.

every time updating a table with count will have same affect as with cron, even when you are updating with cron, it may take time to update all for a large table.in that period of time you can't show update.

***My suggestion is, to count favorites once after login, and keep it in session, every time user favorite a product increment count of session as well in insert in table (as you do) and display the value from session.***

Answer (score 0):

From performance point of view the **alternative B.1** will be the best, because it won't affect the user, but sometimes it won't be up-to-date.

If you want the data to be always updated then use the **alternative B.2** (trigger for update or delete), but this could be slow on adding/deleting favourites (depending on data count).